# How to locate reference tokens to revoke based on the user?

Tags: identityserver3

I configured my IdSvr client to return reference tokens to make them revocable.  I'm also using the IdentityServer.EntityFramework library to store the generated reference tokens in the Tokens table.  The Token Revocation endpoint requires the token to revoke.  As an administrator I want to call revocation but I don't know the access token as the key is stored hashed in the database.  How would the administrator locate the tokens to revoke for a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revoke by subject and client id.

Comment: Is there additional documentation other than this [link](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/revocation.html)?   This states that the unhashed token is required and doesn't say anything about revoking by subject.

Comment: You're looking for this method: 

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/ITransientDataRepository.cs#L65

On this interface:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/ITokenHandleStore.cs

Comment: Ok, I missed that.  I'm looking at it from the TokenRevocationClient in IdentityModel that only exposes the version of RevokeAsync that requires the token.

Comment: Did you managed to revoke by subject and client id? I can't figure out how to do it on Logout event. I have two scenarios , 1) Admin logs out other user, 2) User logs himself out from all other devices.