# How do I revoke a persisted reference token in Identity Server 3

Tags: access-token, identityserver3

I have an Authentication service built on Identity Server 3. I recently switched it from JWTs to reference tokens and implemented SignOutAsync in my UserService to revoke the tokens when the user signs out. The code looks like this:

```
    public override Task SignOutAsync(SignOutContext context)
    {
        string subjectId = GetSubjectId(context);
        _tokenHandleStore.RevokeAsync(subjectId, context.ClientId);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

And that code appears to work. (The ITokenHandleStore interface and RevokeAsync method were recommended in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360090/how-to-locate-reference-tokens-to-revoke-based-on-the-user).) 
If I copy the reference token, I can use it to access my services up until the user signs out. Then the reference token no longer works. Just as I'd expect.

Then I introduced persistent storage of the reference tokens using Identity Server's built-in Entity Framework implementation for operational data. The tokens are written to and purged from the data store as I expect, but they no longer appear to be revoked when the user signs out. I can copy the reference token and use it to access the services, even after the user has signed out.

I've stepped through the code so I know my SignOutAsync method is being called and _tokenHandleStore.RevokeAsync is being called.

Is ITokenHandleStore.RevokeAsync the right method to call? What should I see in the database Tokens table when a token is revoked? Will it be deleted or modified? I am seeing no change to the token data in the data store. The persistent storage and revocation are both built-in features of Identity Server, but do they know about each other? Does the built-in implementation of ITokenHandleStore detect the use of persistent storage and revoke those tokens? Or do I need to extend that method in some way or call a custom method?